# Code-formatting error occurs when composing post on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting, quality-filter

Code formatting error occurs when I tried to post a question on Stack Overflow.

#### Error message

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

#### My Post Script

```
**Expected result**

A button can act in a way like a toggle, such that,
(1) first time clicking on it, the button moves rightward;
(2) second time clicking on it, the button moves leftward;
(3) third time clicking on it, the button moves rightward;
(4) and so on.

**Problem**

the flag variable `flagToggleButton` cannot be used in button's OnClickListener event listener callback function.

**Main.java**:

<!-- language: lang-java -->

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class Main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            
            final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            boolean flagToggleButton = false;
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (flagToggleButton == false) {
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, 
                                           R.anim.animation_move_right);
                        b.startAnimation(anim);
                        flagToggleButton = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, 
                                           R.anim.animation_move_left);
                        b.startAnimation(anim);
                        flagToggleButton = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try formatting your list to be an actual list, or possibly ditch the semicolons. My guess is that it's probably triggering based on multiple lines ending with a semicolon (which you would commonly see in code).

Comment: Hooray~ That's the answer! Thank you~

Comment: @animuson nice catch, worthy of answer! :)

Comment: The still-alive Stack Exchange bug, saying *not properly formatted as code*, is easy to reproduce with a minimalistic version of your Markdown:
`that,\n
(1) first;\n
(2) second;\n
(3) third;\n
`