# Why can't I post links on separate lines without it bugging me about bad code formatting?

Tags: bug, quality-filter

From my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863865/1599699), this code just on its own does not work:

```
See also:
[NTFS Junction Point][1]<br/>
[NTFS Symbolic Link][2]<br/>
[Symbolic Link][3]<br/>


[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Creating_or_deleting_a_junction_point
[2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link
[3]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link
```

and it gives the following error:

"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: I just edited your post by putting two spaces af the end of each line. That seemed to work. You could also add `<br\>` to the end of the line.

Comment: Your post has all the signs of the infamous "not properly formatted as code" bug.
Fortunately, your code can no longer be used to reproduce that bug.
Here are two examples for which the bug is *still* very much alive:
[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364748#comment1290985_364748) and
[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186951#comment1290986_186951).

Answer (score 5):

[You can](http://meta.stackexchange.com)
[if you](http://meta.stackexchange.com)
[want](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Which is written like this...

```
[You can][1]<br>[if you][2]  
[want][3]
```

I.e. stick a `<br>` between them or add a couple of spaces at the end of the line before a newline.

Comment: It's not letting me post in the other post. This is NOT an answer to my problem. I'm still working out exactly why it's not letting me post in the other site but it is here. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: If you're trying to post on StackOverflow you must post code as well if you post a link. It's an attempt to get people to write everything in the question rather than saying see my problem here by clicking on this link.

Comment: Though inserting <br/> tags in the post that's not working does make it work; however, that doesn't explain why those <br/> tags are necessary just for me to post in the first place and why it thinks I'm formatting code improperly.

Answer (score 0):

If the below works, then the problem is irreproducible on MetaStackExchange, though it occurred on StackOverflow.

I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links... Can someone try out the 3 links for me?

See also:
[NTFS Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Creating_or_deleting_a_junction_point)
[NTFS Symbolic Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)