# Trying to submit a question without any code..... and getting a code-formatting error

Tags: support, code-formatting, quality-filter

Below is a screenshot of what I'm trying to post, it includes literally no code... and it's giving me a code-format error and will not let me post. I tried making the file names code, as you can see, and it still doesn't like it. I'm ready to give up.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: What exactly does the message say?  The most common one is "It looks like you have code that is not formatted as code".  I think I saw one previously when someone had a list of links like you have, so they are probably your issue.  But as a side note, your question is not good.  Making people go to external links and dig through a 40 minute tutorial and all of your code is very rude and a very poor question.  You should try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first and if you still have a problem, then post that code.

Comment: I definitely didn't make them go through all of my code... I posted very clearly what my issue was, and specifically where it was, and specifically what step I was on..... did you read it?

Comment: It'd be better of a person didn't have to follow a link to get to the most useful information in your question. (I've converted your link to an inline image; that's a bit better.)

Comment: @yelluhjelluh I'm not trying to be difficult, but I am trying to save you time and trouble.  Strip the fluff out and your question boils down to "I am doing X,,Y,Z.  I have a problem, I am getting this error, go to these links to help me figure it out".  It has the makings of a respectable question, but you are missing the last critical step and that is to remove the links.  If someone needs to visit them in order to solve your problem, then it is not a good answer.  Make the question self-contained and it will be good.

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions:

- Remove "Thank in advance". It's noise.
- The strings "No controller specified for top level element." and "Cannot resolve class or package projectX" should be in quote notation (or simply "quoted"), rather than as an inline code block.
- Put a blank line before the list of links. Consider putting them in an unordered list.

  - I also don't see the actual links, just the Markdown link notation. I *suspect* that that's what's making the filter think you have unformatted code.
- Put a blank line between your paragaphs.

Comment: Whether this is actually a good question for the site where it's being asked is another matter.

Answer (score 3):

I typed the text exactly as it appears in your example.  **I did not receive any code format issues.**

**I was not exactly sure what the vertical-pipe-looking character was** above "Here are the links..."

You can also see some [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186951/code-formatting-error-occurs-when-composing-post-on-stack-overflow) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254504/unable-to-post-answer-with-formatted-code).  They mainly talk about posts that LOOK like they contain code but is not properly formatted, which seems likely in yours.

Or check out the [authoritative guide on formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: (I think the vertical-pipe-looking character is the typing cursor...)

Comment: I'm so used to screenshots not capturing the cursor, I didn't even consider that.  Thanks!